# Website Page not displayed in Windows 7 IE

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, internet-explorer, webserver

We have recently updated an internal web server application. After the update the following behaviour is occurring:

The website loads fine in Firefox, Chrome, and IE (if Windows 10).

The website loads a "Page cannot be displayed" in IE on Windows 7.

When loading the site, the authentication page seems to work fine but after authenticating, we are redirected to this page cannot be displayed. We have tested on various hosts on our network, off our network, and all different types of Windows 7 and Windows 10 builds with varying levels of IE updates.

We are running the latest version of IE 11 on Windows 7. We have tested various levels of minor update (11.0.42xxx) and prior.

If we run fiddler with SSL decryption, the site works fine. The failures occur most often on our internal network, but have also occurred (though not as often) on external networks.

Can anyone offer advice on how to troubleshoot further or troubleshooting webserver/client methodologies?

Update: The web page loads fine after a refresh. After refreshing the page, the web page loads (though CSS is slightly wonky) then after a second refresh, the page displays as it should.

Update2: we believe this may be an issue with the way IE on Windows 7 is handling GZIP compression though we are still unsure as to why.

Comment: So what version of IE are you using?  Are you running IE11 on Windows 7?  If you are not running IE11, is there a specific reason, you are not running the current version of IE on Windows 7?

Comment: Yes, we are running the latest version of IE 11 on Windows 7. We have tested various levels of minor update (11.0.42xxx) and prior.

Comment: Update your question....

Comment: Have you checked the HOSTFILE and DNS entries?

Comment: Yes. And issue is occurring on many different hosts (tested at least 20 different desktops).

Answer (score 0):

This smells like an SSL issue. I recently had a similar issue that was caused by Windows not trusting SHA-1 signed certificates anymore (after 2017-01-01).

But it might also be that your application have upgraded the TLS version, and doesn't support older versions. I believe that Windows 7 doesn't have TLS 1.1 and 1.2 enabled by default, so that might be the issue here.

To enable TLS 1.1 and 1.2 on Windows 7, here is a guide:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/3140245/update-to-enable-tls-1.1-and-tls-1.2-as-a-default-secure-protocols-in-winhttp-in-windows

Please note thet if you have IE11 installed on Windows 7, then TLS 1.1 and 1.2 should already be enabled.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Tried and this did not resolve my issue. I have updated the post with some odd behavior.